# Missing the system references from Project in vs 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am working in vs 2015 and have 10 project in my solution, i Checked out the project from TFS all other projects are working fine but one of mu project is producing errors the following error and all the system references are missing from the project.I have reload the reference from framework and also form nuget but it still missing. Please help

Severity Code Description Project File Line Error This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props. Web.PlasmaDATA D:\Official\Project\Version 2 .x tfs\Web.PlasmaDATA\Web.PlasmaDATA.csproj 177

Comment: Do you have project.json file in that project? Your own project references (e.g: PlasmaData) can also be a reason. Check all updated projects targeting to same .NET full framework/core, whichever applicable and try again.

Comment: i don't have any project.json file in project but the targeting is same of all project